# Generate a seasonal dummy

Tags: r, time-series, dummy-variable

I would like to create a seasonal dummy. Specifically, I want the variable to equal 1 every June and 0 otherwise. I would like the dummy variable output stored in mat1[,2]

Setup:

```
start = as.Date("1926-07-01")
end = as.Date("2019-07-01")
dates = seq(from = start, to = end, by = "month")
mat1 <- matrix(nrow =1117, ncol =2)
mat1[,1] = dates
```

Answer (score 1):

Extract the month from dates and check if the month is "June".

```
data.frame(dates = dates, isJune = +(format(dates, "%m") == "06"))
```

We can also use `regex` to identify if it's the 6th month

```
data.frame(dates = dates, isJune = +(grepl(".*-06-.*", dates)))
```